# Check if time is past a predefined time

Tags: power-automate

I have a flow where a user can fill in a datetime, i wish to check if the input date is not in the past and if the submission date time is less than today at 10:40 AM.

So i have to get the date from the inputfield en and the time from the submissiondate and check if they are less than today at 10:40am.

Which is the best way to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a complete solution but it gives you the kind of pattern you should consider.

I've broken it out for ease.  This is the flow with the expressions at each step ...

[image: Flow]

I've converted the date and time to my own regional location, you should ultimately do the same.

##### Step 1 - Initialize Current DateTime (String)

```
formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(), 'AUS Eastern Standard Time'), 'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt')
```

##### Step 2 - Initialize Today 10:40 AM (String)

```
concat(formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(), 'AUS Eastern Standard Time'), 'dd/MM/yyyy'), ' 10:40 AM')
```

##### Step 3 - Initialize Date Comparison (Boolean)

```
less(parseDateTime(variables('Current DateTime')), parseDateTime(variables('Today 10:40 AM')))
```

The last step will produce the boolean comparison result that you can use in subsequent actions.